# Getting an error "Method call expected" from a switch statement in Android

Tags: java, android

I have written the following switch statement, but I am getting an error. Would someone help me to fix it?

Here is the error:

> Method call expected

Here is the code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.share:
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Share Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.setting:
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Setting Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Shared. please check it now

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Method call expected

Comment: Two error which I can see in this method. 1. Change Switch to switch and 2.  return true or return false;

Answer (score 2):

`Switch` should be lowercase `switch`.

All java keywords are lowercase.

Comment: okay thanks... i was out of mind..